# Time-varying covariates in longitudinal analysis

Tags: panel-data

Let's say that my dataset is in long format. I have a treatment variable that is time-varying, so the individual will NOT receive the treatment initially, but as time goes on, he/she does. How can I take into account that treatment is time-dependent? I was thinking that including the interaction term time*treatment would handle that, but I am not sure. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Basically, I just want to know if including an interaction term between time and treatment would make sure I take into account that treatment is time-dependent.

Comment: If I answered your question to your satisfaction, you can accept my answer by clicking on the check mark under the voting arrows.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're analyzing the data in long format, it's enough to include a term for treatment. Since every observation gets a row, any two observations can have a different value of the treatment variable, even for the same subject. You might still want a time-by-treatment interaction, but this concerns something different from the plain treatment effect: it captures how the effect of treatment itself depends on the time.